# How to unhide an overriden function?

Tags: matlab, built-in, overriding

Suppose I have my own function named `zeros` on the Matlab path. Now I want to call the built-in `zeros`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [builtin](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html) function:

```
builtin(function, arg1, ..., argN)
```

In your case e.g.:

```
builtin('zeros', 50)
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to get a handle to the buil-in `zeros`?

Comment: If you've overridden the builtin `zeros` with your own zeros, you can change directory to `\toolbox\matlab\elmat` (which is where the builtin `zeros` lives, and get a handle to it with `h = @zeros`. This works as when you're in that directory, the builtin is ahead of yours on the path. When you return to your previous directory, `h` will still be a handle to the builtin.

Comment: PS DON'T override `zeros`. Even the my `doc` command doesn't work now, thanks :)

Comment: Here's a better way: `h = @(x)builtin('zeros', x(:))`